# LitExtension Sociallogin facebook error: "Sorry, could not retrieve your facebook first name. Please try again"

Tags: facebook, magento, facebook-graph-api, magento-1.9

I currently cannot signup/login using Facebook for my Magento site. I am using LitExtension Sociallogin Plugin. When I printed the array  $userInfo in facebook controller _connectback() I am getting just two parameters 'name' and 'id'.

Even if I split the name to first name and last name it gets stuck as it doesn't get the email id of the user. I wasn't facing this issue earlier.

Comment: Seems there is an issue with facebook api v2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!!..The issue was with facebook api v2.4. The given solution should work for Inchoo plugin also however i have not tested it. For litextension sociallogin plugin, the file which i modified is: app/code/community/LitExtension/Sociallogin/controllers/FacebookController.php

In _connectCallback():

```
$fields = array(
         'id', 'name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
          );
$userInfo = $client->api('/me?fields=' . implode(',', $fields));
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Facebook API green light - proceed
$client = Mage::getSingleton('le_sociallogin/facebook_client');

// replace this line
$userInfo = $client->api('/me');

//with below code
$userInfo = $client->api('/me','GET', array(
    'fields' => 'id,name,first_name,last_name,link,birthday,gender,email,picture.type(large)'
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Worked perfectly. If we add birthday, then the fb app must be reviewed by the fb team. normally take about 3-5 days to that.